# Is there a command for touching an object or a colour in turtle python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my own ping pong game so when the ball touches the bar it bounces but i don't know the command for touching a colour or an object. This is my code:

```
#imports
import random
import turtle
import time
import winsound
#turtle
x = 0
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("red")
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.penup()
background = turtle.Screen()
background.bgcolor("turquoise")
bar = turtle.Turtle()
bar.shape("square")
bar.shapesize(1, 5, 1)
bar.penup()
bar.speed(100000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
bar.sety(-70)
ball.left(1)
ball.backward(1)
def sp():
    while True:
        if ball.distance(bar) < 2:
            ball.left(1)
            ball.backward(1)
        else:
            ball.right(1)
            ball.forward(1)
        if bar.xcor == -300 or bar.xcor == 300:
            time.sleep(1)
            
def l():    
    bar.backward(25)
def r():
    bar.forward(25)
background.onkey(l, "Left")
background.onkey(r, "Right")
background.onkey(sp, "Up")
turtle.listen()
background.mainloop()
```

The bar is moved with the arrows and the ball moves. What's the command for an object touching another one?

Comment: You've written `bar.speed(100000000000000000000000000000000000000000)`. For fastest speed of turtle, type `bar.speed(0)`

Comment: okay but what is the command for touching a colour or an object?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how far the turtle is from an object, use the distance() method.

Exmaple:

```
if ball.distance(Your Object) < 28:
    #do something
```

You can put for the distance to the object a number between 25 and 30, if you like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about collision you do this

```
if ball.pos() == (name of paddle).pos():
   ## run your command
```